# C# NUnit Selenium - Passing Objects from SetUp to TestCase

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, automated-tests, nunit

I am not understanding how the scoping works on a test case.

```
[TestFixture]
class MockTests
{
    [Setup]
    private void StartTest()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        TestLogger logger = new TestLogger();
    }

    [TestCase(TestName = "mock1")]
    {
        //Problem is here. Driver and logger "does not exist in the current context"
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://my.url.com");
        logger.Out("Hello! I cannot be accessed!");
    }

    [TestCase(TestName = "mock2")]
    {
        //I now have a new instance of driver and logger in my mock2 test
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://my.url.com");
        logger.Out("Hello! I am a new Instance of TestLogger!");
    }

    [TearDown]
    private void EndTest()
    {
        driver.Quit();
        logger.PrintReport(TestContext.name, TestContext.status);
    }
}
```

It seems to me the SetUp is pointless if you can't use it to access unique Instances of Objects across the tests. I see vars/objects used in a similar fashion, but with the vars/objects defined in the scope of the class; ie: private IWebDriver driver;

So if I have 25 tests inside a single test fixture and run them in parallel; the test functions could be talking to the wrong driver instead of creating unique Instance inside every TestCase.

How do I do this so I know my TestLogger and driver are indeed unique? How do I pass them between the SetUp Test and TearDown?

And TestLogger is just an example. It could be anything like a User object model:

```
public class User
{
    public string fName{get; set;}
    public string lName{get; set;}
    //etc...
}
```

Maybe I just am not understand how the test should be setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables `driver` and `logger` are local to your setup method. They go out of scope when the method exits.

If you want your tests to have access to anything setup in the setup method, then it has to be saved in a member variable.

Your "test cases" are not compilable. They are not methods. They do not appear to make any use of the arguments you are passing: "mock1" and "mock2". Most likely, you want to user `[Test]` rather than `[TestCases]`.

Most examples I have seen of web testing create the driver only once per test fixture, using [OneTimeSetUp] rather than [SetUp]. Do you really want to change the driver for each test? If so, and if you use a member variable, then you can't run your test cases in parallel because they will interfere with one another. Fortunately, for many test bases, running fixtures in parallel gives sufficiently good performance.

Update: Following your comment, it's clear you want to have a separate driver per test case. You have two choices...

1. Do not run test cases in parallel. Use `[Parallelizable]` on the fixture, causing it to run in parallel with other fixtures, but with it's test cases running serially because you don't have `Children` in the scope. If you have a bunch of other fixtures, with which you can run in parallel, I think you will find this to be pretty effective.
2. Run the cases in parallel, but don't use the SetUp method to create a driver. Instead, create it in each test. If it takes more than a line, use a method to return it. Each of your test cases will have a separate driver and you eliminate any chance of the tests stepping on one another.

FWIW, this example is leading me to want to take another look at how to provide better fixture separation for parallel tests without rewriting the whole framework.

Comment: Yes I do want to change the driver for each test case. The way I have them organized is on a per issue basis (issues per sprint). So each Fixture contains the issue, each test is a variation of the issue. So each test needs it's own driver so it is not influencing the other tests. 

Is that a good way to setup them up? I am new to testing and was handed this project and told to make it happen! So a "best practices" lesson wouldn't hurt me a bit!

Comment: In that case, you have two choices.... don't run cases in parallel or use separate drivers for each test case. I'll edit my answer with the details.

BTW... you are far from the first person to be new to testing and yet trying to deal with some fairly advanced concepts in NUnit. What's with that? Can't companies give folks something simple to start with? :-)

Answer (score 0):

As Charlie said they must be a member variable to scope across the various tests inside a fixture(class).

My misunderstanding was thinking the SetUp and TearDown would be within the same scope as a test case. I had it in my head that was how NUnit worked...

This is definitely NOT the case. (no pun intended, ha)

So here is a working solution that shows unique instances that works across all the tests in parallel:

```
[TestFixture]
class MockTests
{
    IWebDriver driver;
    TestLogger logger;

    [Setup]
    private void StartTest()
    {
       //This instantiates a new driver and logger each test 
       driver = new ChromeDriver();
       logger = new TestLogger();
    }

    [TestCase(TestName = "mock1")]
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Driver: " + driver.CurrentWindowHandle);
        logger.Out("Hello! I am unique now! 1");
    }

    [TestCase(TestName = "mock2")]
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Driver: " + driver.CurrentWindowHandle);
        logger.Out("Hello! I am unique now! 2");
    }

    [TestCase(TestName = "mock3")]
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Driver: " + driver.CurrentWindowHandle);
        logger.Out("Hello! I am unique now! 3");
    }

    [TearDown]
    private void EndTest()
    {
        driver.Quit();
        logger.PrintReport(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name, TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: The drivers will be different until the code happens to execute in a sequence like: SetUp1 -> SetUp2 => Test1 => Test2, which can easily happen in a parallel environment.

Comment: So I could still run into problems. I ran 115 tests in parallel and didn't see any issues so far. I am looking at setting up a fixture order. Maybe that will help alleviate the problems further. Any recommendations then? Just put them all in their own fixture? That seems counterproductive to other Integration Testing workflows and patterns I've seen.

Comment: If NUnit were designed for integration testing, it would be easier. It isn't. :-( However, isolation by use of a separate driver per test case is a unit-testing pattern. Most web integration tests I have seen use the same browser instance for multiple tests. Anyway, you have to adjust your techniques to your tools.